# How to switch website for a BrowserView without waiting for page reload?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, electron

Let's say I have a `BrowserView` inside a `BrowserWindow`:

```
browserWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 1200, height: 600 });
browserWindow.webContents.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/top_toolbar.html');

let browserView1 = new BrowserView({ webPreferences: { nodeIntegration: false }});
browserWindow.setBrowserView(browserView1);
browserView1.setBounds({ x: 0, y: 50, width: 600, height: 600 }); // y=50 to keep top toolbar
browserView1.webContents.loadURL('https://www.twitter.com');
```

When I click on a UI button (another "tab", like in a browser), I'd like to change the URL to another website (such as https://www.gmail.com).

When I'll click back to the first "tab", I'd like that the `BrowserView` recovers the previous website (Twitter) and all its browsing history. Obviously, using:

```
browserView1.webContents.loadURL('https://www.twitter.com');
```

again wouldn't be a good solution because there would be a page loading waiting time.

Instead I'd like to restore the previous state of the `BrowserView` **instantly** (i.e. < 50 ms), exactly like when you click on a tab in a browser like Chrome or Firefox: if the website in the tab has already been loaded before, clicking on the tab just re-displays it.

**Question: how to store and then restore instantly a `BrowserView` state?** i.e. without requiring to reload the page?

[image]

Comment: Use multiple BrowserViews, and show/hide them.

Comment: @ChrisG: Electron 4 can't have multiple BrowserViews AFAIK, it requires Electron 5 (still beta), is that right?

Comment: you can have multiple instance of browserview, only can't display them at once, You can attach / detach desired instance when you need to display specific one.

Comment: @Basj I haven't tested it, but I imagine something like this: `var bw1 = new BrowserView(...); var bw2 = new BrowserView(...);` Then `browserWindow.setBrowserView(bw1);` to show the first, and `browserWindow.setBrowserView(bw2);` to show the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to have multiple BrowserViews and switch between them. That way each will remember its history.

```
var browserViews = [];
var activeBW;

function addAndSwitchToTab() {
  activeBW = browserViews.length;
  browserViews[activeBW] = new BrowserView();
  browserWindow.setBrowserView(activeBW);
}
```

Start with the first one:

```
addAndSwitchToTab();
```

When the user opens a new tab, just call the function again.

Comment: Thank you very much @ChrisG! Here is a linked question (how to have the different `BrowserView`s "isolated" in terms of cookies/accounts connected), in case you have an idea: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55061908

Answer (score 1):

Try this for button click:

```
 onClick(){
        const shell = require('electron').shell;
        event.preventDefault();
        shell.openExternal('https://www.twitter.com');
      }
```