# Having two isolated (in terms of history/cookies/localstorage) BrowserViews in the same BrowserWindow with Electron

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, electron

Let's say I have two `BrowserView` in the same `BrowserWindow` and an UI button allowing the user to switch between showing `bv1` or `bv2` (like the "tab" system in browsers like Firefox, Chrome, that allows you to switch between the different pages):

```
browserWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 1200, height: 600 });

let bv1 = new BrowserView({ webPreferences: { nodeIntegration: false }});
bv1.setBounds({ x: 0, y: 0, width: 1200, height: 600 });
bv1.webContents.loadURL('https://www.twitter.com');

let bv2 = new BrowserView({ webPreferences: { nodeIntegration: false }});
bv2.setBounds({ x: 0, y: 0, width: 1200, height: 600 });
bv2.webContents.loadURL('https://www.twitter.com');

browserWindow.setBrowserView(bv1);
```

and when a button (like a "tab" in a browser) is pressed:

```
browserWindow.setBrowserView(bv2);
```

I noticed that these two `BrowserView`:

- share the same cookies/localStorage (which I don't want!), i.e. if the first is connected to an account, the second will be connected as well to the same account
- keep history and cookies after restart of the Electron app (this is good and wanted indeed!)

**Question: how to have the two `BrowserView` *totally isolated* in terms of cookies/localStorage/history (and thus `bv1` could be connected to one Twitter account and `bv2` to another one)?**

Comment: Not sure whether this will work, but did you try with `webPreferences.contextIsolation`? From the official docs, it looks like it provides an isolated javascript context, not sure whether this will impact the browser view though, but you may give it a shot: https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window (the docs are under browser-window, but the BrowserView constructor accepts the browser-window config as argument). Otherwise, you may **inject a session instead**: https://electronjs.org/docs/api/session (check webPreferences.session)

Comment: Thank you @briosheje, I tried with `contextIsolation` but with no success. Would you have a code sample with session injection? i.e. how to isolate both BrowserViews with different sessions?

Comment: Why not 2 BrowserWindows?

Comment: @LeonardoBuscemi I'd like to be able to navigate between the different isolated "tabs" in the same browser window.

Comment: You could use a third Browser Windows (as "navigation bar") and show one at a time, passing through the main process. Using frameless BW it should have the same aspect of BrowserView.

Comment: @LeonardoBuscemi Yes, but when you move one window, the 2 other frameless BW should move too, so you have to program this. Same thing if you resize one window, the 2 other windows have to resize, etc. This is probably much hassle, don't you think so? (I don't know) What is the benefit of using BrowserWindows instead of BrowserViews? Thank you for your comments!

Comment: ok, I understand, I forget the "responsive" problems! 
The benefit of BWs is they are isolated as you want!

Comment: @LeonardoBuscemi, oh I see! Then it might be interesting, if they are isolated by default... Feel free to post an answer if you have an idea of how to make the windows work together with an UI similar to a single window. Thanks again!

Comment: @Basj Making the two windowViews resize won't be too much of an issue, you can just listen to the resize event on the window and set the width/height of both window views to that. Was my answer below any help at all in solving your issues?

Comment: @JokerDan It's on my todo list for tomorrow to run it / test it / give feedback (haven't had the time to run the code today), thanks already very much for having posted it!

Comment: I was wrong, also BrowserWindows shares localStorage, cookies and so on... Sorry for that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, I managed to get this working but in a very, very, roundabout way. Effectively session hijacking your own session, saving and loading it on app close/open. Code below with some comments, prefaced with some useful links. This worked when running as dev, and when running with a build application.

You may need to look into possible security issues here with storing cookies locally like this.

The only thing I have not tackled in this answer is:

> keep history ... after restart of the Electron app

---

- [Electron-Json-Storage Package](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-json-storage) - We use this to store/retrieve cookies. The default location for storage is `C:\Users\%user%\AppData\Roaming\%appname%\storage`.
- [Electron Cookies documentation](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/cookies)
- [Electron Session documentation](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/session) - Notably the `session.fromPartition` docs.

---

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, BrowserView, globalShortcut, session } = require('electron');
const eJSONStorage = require('electron-json-storage');

// Our two different sesions, views, and base URL for our 'tabs'.
let bv1Session, bv2Session = session;
let bv1, bv2 = BrowserView;
const appTabUrl = 'https://www.twitter.com';

app.on('ready', () => {
  const width = 1200; const height = 600;
  let b1Active = true;

  // Our browser window
  browserWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: width,
    height: height,
  });

  // Our first browser window with it's own session instance.
  bv1Session = session.fromPartition('persist:bv1Session', { cache: true });
  bv1 = createBrowserView(appTabUrl, bv1Session, width, height);
  loadCookieState('view1Cookies', bv1Session);

  // Our second browser window with it's own session instance.
  bv2Session = session.fromPartition('persist:bv2Session', { cache: true });
  bv2 = createBrowserView(appTabUrl, bv2Session, width, height);
  loadCookieState('view2Cookies', bv2Session);

  // Our initial setting of the browserview
  browserWindow.setBrowserView(bv1);

  // Our shortcut listener and basic switch mechanic
  // Set to [CTRL + /] for windows or [CMD + /] for OSX
  globalShortcut.register('CommandOrControl+/', () => {
    b1Active ? browserWindow.setBrowserView(bv2) : browserWindow.setBrowserView(bv1);
    b1Active = !b1Active
  });
});

// When the app closes, exit gracefully.
// Unregister keypress listener, save cookie states, exit the app.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  globalShortcut.unregisterAll();
  saveCookieState('view1Cookies', bv1Session);
  saveCookieState('view2Cookies', bv2Session);
  app.quit();
})

// Helper method to generate a browser view.
function createBrowserView(url, session, width, height) {
  let browserView = new BrowserView({
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false,
      nodeIntegrationInWorker: false,
      session: session
    }
  });
  browserView.setBounds({ x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height });
  browserView.webContents.loadURL(url);
  return browserView;
}

// Method that takes a session name, and our current session to save its state.
function saveCookieState(sessionName, currentSession) {
  currentSession.cookies.get({}, (_, cookies) => {
    cookies.forEach(cookie => {
      // URL is a required paramater, take it from the domain with a little parsing.
      // Twitter always uses HTTPS otherwise, we would need to check for http vs https too.
      const cDomain = !cookie.domain.startsWith('.') ? `.${cookie.domain}` : cookie.domain;
      cookie.url = `https://www${cDomain}`
    });
    // Save the set of cookies against the session name.
    eJSONStorage.set(sessionName, cookies, err => {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
    });
  });
}

// Method that loads a session based on its name, into a session created by us.
function loadCookieState(sessionName, currentSession) {
  eJSONStorage.get(sessionName, (error, cookieData) => {
    // Check for empty object returned, this means no saved sessions.
    if (Object.entries(cookieData).length === 0) {
      return;
    }
    if (error) {
      throw error;
    }
    // If we have saved sessions and no errors, load the sessions.
    cookieData.forEach(cookie => currentSession.cookies.set(cookie, error => {
      if (error) console.error(error);
    }));
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @JokenDan, it seems to totally work! Even the `The only thing I have not tackled in this answer is: keep history after restart` : it seems to work! Does it for you too? I'll continue my tests, and will post if anything seems to break this, but so far, it seems to work. PS: what do you want to do with `const cDomain = !cookie.domain.startsWith('.') ? '.${cookie.domain}' : cookie.domain;
      cookie.url = 'https://www${cDomain}'`?

Comment: So, the `url` property is not populated on the cookie when we get them, but it is a required property when we set them. So here, we are taking the domain for the cookie (Some cases it is `.twitter.com` and others `auth.twitter.com` for instance). When saving, it has to be a fully qualified URL (`https://www.twitter.com`) - So we are just doing a check for the `.` and constructing the URL properly from the domain, to be a full URL. Like I said in the comment, if you want to use websites that mix http and https, then you will need to account for and do a check for that.

Comment: Hi @Dan_, do you remember why you manually stored the cookies with `eJSON storage`? It seems this is unneeded:  `session.fromPartition('persist:bv1Session', ...)` will automatically create a persistent `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\appname\Partitions\bv1session\Cookies` file for us.

Comment: I tried to remove the `saveCookieState` and `loadCookieState` and ... it seems to work. Can you confirm? Or probably there was a specific reason why you did an additional serialization/storage of cookies with JSON, and not let `fromPartition` do everything for us about cookies?